# Como inverter a ordem de resultados de loop em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, loop, while

Escrevi um código baseado em tutoriais que vi para mostrar informações do Banco de Dados de comentários de usuários em tabelas mas gostaria que ele invertesse a ordem dos resultados.Como posso fazer isso?

```
<?php

// se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados

if($total > 0) {

    // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados

    do {

?>

        <table>

            <tr>

                <td>ID</td>

                <td id="um"><?= $linha['coment_id']?></td>

            </tr>



            <tr>

                <td>Veiculo</td>

                <td id="um"><?= $linha['mododeuso']?></td>

            </tr>



            <tr>

                <td>Nome</td>

                <td id="um"><?=$linha['user_name']?></td>

            </tr>



            <tr>

                <td>Email</td>

                <td id="um"><?=$linha['user_email']?></td>

            </tr>



            <tr>

                <td>Comentario</td>

                <td id="um"><?=$linha['comentario']?></td>

            </tr>

        </table><br><hr>



<?php

    // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados

    }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));

// fim do if 

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código que possuí a QUERY para selecionar as informações do banco insira a opção ORDER BY **nome_da_tabela_que_voce_quer_ordenar** DESC;

Exemplo:

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM nome_da_tabela WHERE nome_da_tabela_que_voce_quer_ordenar = 'XXXXX' ORDER BY nome_da_tabela_que_voce_quer_ordenar DESC;");
```

Comment: funcionou certinho